# Tool to draw polygon on google map by passing coordinates

Tags: android, maps, coordinates, share

I am doing android app for field drawing and now I am making share function. Is there are any way to pass field coordinates from mobile to maps.google.com, make link, and send this link for example to friend via sms or email, that he just need to push the link and my drawed field will show up to him in browser? Is there any tool to do this or I need to create some web app for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out it

```
// To draw boundray on map
private void drawPolygon() {
    polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions(); // consider new options
    setStrokeWidth();

    for (LatLng latLng : drawCoordinates) {
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(latLng.toString()));
        marker.setVisible(false);

        polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition()).strokeColor(Color.RED);
        polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        polygonOptions.visible(true);
    }
    List<LatLng> points = polygonOptions.getPoints();
    if (!points.isEmpty()) {
        polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
        Log.i("Poly lines","Successfully added polyline on map");
    }
}
```